# Resolution changes when exporting raster from GRASS to Arcmap

Tags: raster, grass-gis, export

I have a raster file of rainfall (floating) in GRASS that I want to export and open in arcmap.

If I look for the raster file in GRASS, it has

```
Rows:         140                                                        |
Columns:      180                                                        |
Total Cells:  25200 
Res:  0:30
```

I use the following command to export this:

```
r.out.gdal input=prec1998.152 type=Float64 output=test nodata=-9999
```

When I open the `test.tif` in Arcmap, it has only only 36 columns, 35 rows and cell size is 0.81191422.

Why after the export, is the raster file getting coarser?

Comment: r.out i think is being governed by g.region. check if it set up to your liking first.

Comment: Yes, see for this: https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Computational_region